How do I (fairly cheaply) fix an uneven & somewhat broken apart basement floor?
My basement floor is somewhat uneven and damaged. Small chunks broken off, areas where there's dips and chunks missing, etc. Possibly some moisture damage as well? There were definite major moisture/leak problems before that we've done some work on mitigating (redirecting gutters away from house, etc.) that's helped some, but it's still somewhat damp. The house was a flip by a developer so I guess fixing this wasn't a priority.
Here's the thing: the floors are so uneven that it's hard to place shelves. There's some cracks, rubble, dips, etc. Nothing huge, but enough to be annoying. I've read about various quick-setting concrete and/or epoxy products to achieve a usable floor, but I'm not sure how to evaluate which approach would be best given the condition of my basement (see pictures). It doesn't seem so badly cracked that fully cutting the concrete or jackhammering everything out and redoing it seems necessary. I was thinking of just putting a new surface of something over top of this to even it out, but some online advice seems against that kind of fix.
I'm fairly sure the main moisture issues are primarily leakage through walls, though the sump pump running during wet times does suggest maybe there's groundwater from below as well. Not sure how to tell, nor if it is relevant to my desire to fix the floors.
I looked around this site and read a related question (Best way to fix an uneven floor), but I don't have a sloping problem, just dips and some cracks, and the existing damage makes me wary of doing random fixes.
We are primarily using the basement for storage, so it doesn't need to be super nice.
My major limitation is cost - I'd like this to be something I could do myself or with a buddy over the course of a few weeks of evening/weekend work, and without buying expensive/big tools. I'm decently handy for smaller projects (retiling a bathroom, etc.) but this would be a major step up. But I'm into it so would love to learn.


[3


You're right that local patches aren't the way to go. This needs replacement, really, but a photo of the scene rather than just closeups would inform good suggestions.

The dampness/moisture issues should be fixed first.  The damp will get into most things you store down there.

So, as addressed in https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/285835/18078 if you need a level spot to set shelves, you can mortar 4 bricks to the floor, adjusting the mortar so the tops of the bricks are level. Gets the shelf legs above minor wetness, too. As for the loose patches, break them up and redo them. Lacking money to burn, you don't need a whole new expensive floor just to store stuff.
